# $\mathbb R^{+}$ is isomorphic to $2^{\aleph}$ copies of $\mathbb Q$

Tags: group-theory, direct-sum

Here is my homework problem.

> Explain why the positive reals $\mathbb{R}^+$ is a divisible abelian group under multiplication. Show that the group $\mathbb{R}^+$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of $2^\aleph$ copies of $\mathbb{Q}$.

I think, unless my professor means something special by "divisible abelian group," that I am supposed to show that $(\mathbb{R}^+, \cdot)$ maps to $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ by the logarithm and that there's an invertible by the exponential. However, it **seems** as if he is asking me to use this fact in demonstrating that $2^\aleph$ copies of $\mathbb{Q}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: Yes, $(\mathbb{R},+)$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. Take a basis of it, count it, and use it to prove your result by writing the space as a direct sum of copies of the field of scalars.

Comment: Any positive real is divisible by any positive integer, that is $nx=r$ has a real solution $x$ is $n$ is a positive integer and $r$ a positive real. This is what is meant by saying that $\mathbb{R}^+$ is a divisible abelian group. Since it is also torsion-free, it must be a direct sum of indecomposable torsion-free divisible groups, i.e. a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Q}.$ Since $\mathbb{R}$ has cardinality $2^\aleph,$ this is how many copies  you need.

Comment: @ChrisLeary Not exactly, for $(\mathbb{R}^{+},\cdot)$ being divisible what it means is that every element has an $n$-th root in the group.

Comment: But you can easily prove this, using the properties of $\exp$!

Comment: @glofactics - Exactly. My comment is a good example of haste makes waste as I dashed it off on a break in the late news on TV. I will record what I wanted to say in an answer below.

Comment: You probably mean $2^{\aleph_0}$. Not $2^\aleph$.

Comment: @glofactics - Just so there is no misunderstanding, my "exactly" was in reference to each positive real having an $n$-th root, not to your opening "not exactly," which was exactly right. When I got in bed after the late news, I realized I had gotten my signals crossed. Needless to say, I did not sleep all that well. When I woke at 6AM, I got up and typed my answer below. After that I slept much better. I really don't like making silly errors like that, but it happens, and we survive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positive reals are an  abelian group under multiplication, while the reals are an abelian group under addition. Working in the the latter case, the group is divisible since the equation $nx=r$ has a real solution for any positive integer $n$ and any real number $r.$ As a torsion-free divisible group, the additive group of reals must therefore be a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Q}.$ Since $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, the number of summands must be $2^{\aleph},$ $\aleph$ being the cardinality of the rationals.

This answers your original question because, as you correctly observed, logarithm provides an isomorphism between the multiplicative group of positive reals and the additive group of reals.

As @glofactics pointed out, $(\mathbb{R},+)$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space since the solution of $nx=r$ gives you a way to define $(1/n)r.$ You can proceed from this perspective easily.

Note that $n0=0$ for any positive integer $n.$ Indeed, we can choose $n$ to be any real number. Thus, we see that $0/0$ is indeterminate, because the expression does not have a unique value. It would be a good exercise to produce examples in which a limit has the indeterminate form $0/0,$ yet the value of the limit will be a specified real number $r.$